# Get ALL post types in WordPress in query_posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using `query_posts` to get a list of most popular posts. I'm using several custom post types, and instead of including all of them in the query, I would like a query that just gets all of them, also if I create more.

This is what I have:

```
query_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => array('posttype1', 'postype2', 'posttype3')
    )
);
```

If I don't include the `post_type`, it only gets the standard post type, `post`. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `'post_type' =>  'any'` for fetching from all post types. See this documentation. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Note: It is highly recommended to use `WP_Query` rather than `query_posts`. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/27998

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm -- I'll look into WP_query, thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
'post_type' => 'any',
```

This gets all posts except revisions. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

So your query would be:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => array('posttype1', 'postype2', 'posttype3')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `get_posts()`, the only work around is to use `'post_type' => get_post_types()`

Example that returns ALL posts of ANY post type:

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => get_post_types(),
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1,
]);
```